# In Excel, with 2 applications open, editing one breaks the VBA-dependent formulae in another

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have two excel documents. One contains info on setting up countries in a strategy game. Another contains info on the stats of the units of those countries.

I keep the both open as I work.

When I edit the Countries document, cells in the Units document which were showing a correct value apparently reevaluate and show `#VALUE!`.

If I select these cells again, select their formula, and hit enter to re-evaluate, the values are once again fine.

The cells that are becoming invalid use some VBA methods I wrote. This is their formula:

```
=SUM(MAP(Table9[Serbia Divs], Table9[Serbia Quantity], LAMBDA(div_name,div_quantity, IF(ISBLANK(div_name), 0, GETDSTAT(div_name, "Manpower")) * div_quantity)))
```

with `GETDSTAT` being the custom UDF. Below is all the VBA code I use: it all belongs to the 'Units' document.

```
Function GETDSTAT(division_name As String, stat_name As String)
    Application.Volatile
    
    index = Application.Match(stat_name, Worksheets("Divisions").ListObjects("DivisionStats").ListColumns("Stats").DataBodyRange, 0)
    GETDSTAT = Worksheets("Divisions").ListObjects("DivisionStats").ListColumns(division_name).DataBodyRange.Item(index)
End Function
```

I suspect my use of Application.Volatile is somehow responsible, but unsure how.

Comment: You don't specify any Workbook objects in your UDF, so if t recalculates when another workbook is active, it will try to reference `Worksheets("Divisions")` in that other workbook and throw an error if that workbook doesn't have a worksheet with that name.